# Fake UDP Response For DNS

Tags: java, networking

As a part of an academic project I am to write a piece of code that can generate fake UDP response. I am doing it using `jnetpcap` and here is my code:

```
public static void SendResponse() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Generating fake response!");
        try {
            String host = "fakeme.example.com";
            int port = XXXX; //This is the port where the DNS lookup service runs.
            byte[] message = "Hello Boyz !".getBytes();
            // Get the internet address of the specified host
            InetAddress address;
            address = InetAddress.getByName("77.**.**.**");

            // Initialize a datagram packet with data and address
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, address, port);
            // Create a datagram socket, send the packet through it, close it.
            DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket();
            dsocket.send(packet);
            dsocket.close();
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sniffer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

It so happens that we have a service, when this piece of code runs the service should return a value. In my case it always fails.

Where have I screwed?

Thanks.

**Additional Information:** The piece of code that calls this is:

```
public static PcapPacketHandler<String> packet_handler(Pcap pcap) {
PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {
            Udp udp = new Udp();

            @Override
            public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {

                if (!packet.hasHeader(udp)) {
                    return; // not a UDP package, skip
                }
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Fake response ");
                        //Send repsonse
                        SendResponse();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Sniffer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
            }
        };
        return jpacketHandler;
    }
```

**Please note:** And I am running this first and then the service (which does a `dns lookup` for the given web address to check if my spoofer is working) in 2 terminal tabs. I am also asked to used a certain port, which I put in the port address of my code. Is that the correct way to do it?

Thanks again.

Comment: A UDP response to what? UDP is connectionless.

Comment: @RonMaupin UDP response for a DNS. Let me add it.